# Restrict npm publish on some fixed servers

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, nexus, credentials

In my organization, I am setting up continuous integration with jenkins 2, and all built artifacts go to a private nexus 3 server (maven and npm modules)

I want to restrict publication to nexus on a set of fixed machines : only the jenkins slaves can publish. The rule is : all projects must be in continuous integration to be released.

**I don't want developpers to be able to publish directly in the private nexus from their workstation.**

Currently I achieved this by putting npm publish token in .npmrc file, in jenkins user home directory.

It works, but this token can be easily stolen by creative users (in their jenkins build, with a simple command like 'more ~.npmrc'). With this token, anybody can publish on the nexus server. Clearly my current configuration is not good.

What are the best practices ? My goal is that all npm module in my private nexus are built from jenkins and not from dev workstations.

Thank you all

Comment: Do you not trust the developers? It might be more productive for you to persuade them not to publish from their machines than to try to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins does provide a mechanism for storing and retrieving credentials via the [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin).  Would this be an option?

For example, if you are in a free style build, you can check the "Use secret text(s) or file(s)" under "Build Environment" to use a secret text/password.

If you are in a Jenkinsfile, you can use a "withCredentials" clause to provide the same information.